# Unlike or not equals for string comparison in NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, nspredicate

I want to get all objects whose attribute "content" is not an empty string.

I already tried "not like", "!=" and "<>", but none of these is working.

In all the documentations I only find the positive comparisons (like, ==,...) but not the negative ones.

Answer (score 4):

`!=` is, in fact, correct. But your problem might lie elsewhere, the `content` property of the object you're trying to match might be `nil`. So either phrase your predicate as `content != "" && content != nil` or, if you use Core Data, set the `content` property to `@""` in `-awakeFromInsert`, so it doesn't default to `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for a predicate created using the string syntax (as opposed to creating the predicate programmatically:)

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT content == \"\""];
```

You can use `NOT` to negate any of the tests (`LIKE`, `IN`, etc.).